# How to create API Gateway Resource Policy that references itself in the Python CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm creating an API that will *ONLY* accept requests made from the GitHub Webhook servers by using a Resource Policy with the GitHub IPs. I've successfully done this using the console and manually creating the Resource Policy, but I'm running into a problem when I'm using the CDK.

Here's my code:

```py
delete_trigger_integration = aws_apigateway.LambdaIntegration(
    trigger_step_lambda, proxy=False, integration_responses=[])

api_policy_document = aws_iam.PolicyDocument()

api = aws_apigateway.RestApi(
    self,
    "GithubWebhookApi",
    rest_api_name=PROJECT_NAME + "-apigateway-trigger-delete",
    default_integration=delete_trigger_integration,
    policy=api_policy_document)

delete_execution_resource = api.root.add_resource("execution")

delete_execution_method = delete_execution_resource.add_method(
    "POST", delete_trigger_integration)
delete_execution_resource.add_cors_preflight(allow_origins=["*"])

create_repo_lambda.add_environment("API_URL",
                                   delete_execution_resource.url)

api_policy_document.add_statements(
    aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        principals=[aws_iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions=["execute-api:Invoke"],
        resources=[api.arn_for_execute_api()]))

api_policy_document.add_statements(
    aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=aws_iam.Effect.DENY,
        actions=["execute-api:Invoke"],
        conditions={
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "192.30.252.0/22", "185.199.108.0/22",
                    "140.82.112.0/20"
                ]
            }
        },
        principals=[aws_iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        resources=[api.arn_for_execute_api()]))
```

I feel like I'm **very** close to having a solution but I can't figure out what it is. The problem with the code above is that I get the `ValidationError: Circular dependency between resources` error when trying to deploy it - which I can understand, the resource policy is addressing the very resource it's inside. But I can't find a way around it in the CDK.

For other resources it's really easy to ad IAM policies after the creation using `aws_iam.add_to_role_policy` but I can't find the equivalent for the `RestApi` class in the CDK. It seems you ***have*** to add the `PolicyDocument` when you declare the `RestApi`.

Also, here's the resource policy that I'm trying to recreate in the CDK (it's those resource ARNs which are causing the problem):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:000000000000:aaaaaaaaaa/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:000000000000:aaaaaaaaaa/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "192.30.252.0/22",
                        "185.199.108.0/22",
                        "140.82.112.0/20"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance!

*Also, you can ignore the empty integration responses - I'm still working on that.*

Comment: Seems that the policy must be defined within the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource in CF also, the doc suggests using `!Join` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy, have you tried that? `resources=[core.Fn.Join('', ['execute-api:/', '*'])]`

Comment: @jogold No I've not tried that but it certainly looks like a possibility. Let me give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @jogold Hey it worked thanks! Feel free to post the solution here - otherwise I'll write it up here in a couple days :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to how the underlying CloudFormation resource works.

As the [`Policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy) must be defined within the [`AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html) resource, it cannot reference itself.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy):

> To set the ARN for the policy, use the `!Join` intrinsic function with `""` as delimiter and values of `"execute-api:/"` and `"*"`.

Which translates into the following in your CDK code:

```py
resources=[core.Fn.join('', ['execute-api:/', '*'])]
```

Comment: And if you wanted to restrict access to specific resources and methods, you can use the string (skip the Join stuff) `execute-api:/stage-name/GET/pets`, per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html

Comment: lower case j in join for python